# Наследование ComObject интерфейсов и назначение атрибутов

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

Есть ли необходимость повторно указывать атрибут типа интерфейса `Com`, если он наследуется от другого `Com` интерфейса, в котором уже был задан тип?

Пример:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("aec22fb8-76f3-4639-9be0-28eb43a67a2e")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDXGIObject
{
    long SetPrivateData([In] ref Guid name, [In] uint dataSize, IntPtr dataPtr);

    long SetPrivateDataInterface([In] ref Guid name, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
        object unknownInterfaceObject);

    long GetPrivateData([In] ref Guid name, out int dataSize, out IntPtr dataPtr);

    long GetParent([In] ref Guid rIId, [Out] out object pParent);
}
```

Далее, его наследником будет `IDXGIFactory`:

```
/// <inheritdoc cref="IDXGIObject"/> />
/// <summary>
///     An IDXGIFactory interface implements methods for generating DXGI objects (which handle fullscreen transitions).
/// </summary>
[ComImport]
[Guid("7b7166ec-21c7-44ae-b21a-c9ae321ae369")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDXGIFactory : IDXGIObject
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Enumerates the adapters (video cards).
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult EnumAdapters(uint numAdapter, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object adapter);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows DXGI to monitor an application's message queue for the alt-enter key sequence (which causes the application
    ///     to switch from windowed to fullscreen or vice versa).
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult MakeWindowAssociation(IntPtr windowHandle, uint flags);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get the window through which the user controls the transition to and from fullscreen.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult GetWindowAssociation(out IntPtr outHandleWindow);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates a swap chain.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult CreateSwapChain(IntPtr lpIUnknown, IntPtr ptr, out IntPtr outPtr);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Create an adapter interface that represents a software adapter.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult CreateSoftwareAdapter(IntPtr moduleHandle, out IntPtr outPtr);
}
```

Есть ли необходимость вновь писать атрибут

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
```

для интерфейса наследника, если он тоже, по сути, является `IUnknown`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путем некоторых манипуляций удалось выяснить, в обязательном порядке стоит соблюдать следующие правила:

1. Наследуемый объект должен переопределять декларацию интерфейса от которого наследуется, перед методами текущего метода, т.е. до их объявлений. (Спасибо за подсказку [@MSDN.WhiteKnight](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240512/msdn-whiteknight)).
2. Интерфейс наследник в обязательном порядке должен иметь атрибут `[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]`, иначе будем иметь проблемы с доступом к памяти.
3. Интерфейс наследник наследуется от интерфейса который для него является базовым лишь для удобства работы с данными интерфейсами.

Таким образом, базовый интерфейс к примеру в данном случае это `IDXGIObject` выглядит так:

```
/// <summary>
///     An IDXGIObject interface is a base interface for all DXGI objects; IDXGIObject supports associating caller-defined
///     (private data) with an object and retrieval of an interface to the parent object.
/// </summary>
[Guid("aec22fb8-76f3-4639-9be0-28eb43a67a2e")]
[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDXGIObject
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Sets an IUnknown interface as private data; this associates application-defined data with the object.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult SetPrivateData(ref Guid name, uint dataSize, IntPtr dataPtr);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Set an interface in the object's private data.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult SetPrivateDataInterface(ref Guid name,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object unknownInterfaceObject);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get a pointer to the object's data.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult GetPrivateData(ref Guid name, out int dataSize, out IntPtr dataPtr);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the parent of the object.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult GetParent(ref Guid rIId, out object pParent);
}
```

Далее от него к примеру наследуется `IDXGIFactory` определение необходимо задавать строго вот так:

```
/// <inheritdoc />
/// <summary>
///     An <see cref="T:Himiko.DXGI.Interfaces.IDXGIFactory" /> interface implements methods for generating DXGI objects (which handle fullscreen
///     transitions).
/// </summary>
[Guid("7b7166ec-21c7-44ae-b21a-c9ae321ae369")]
[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDXGIFactory : IDXGIObject
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Sets an IUnknown interface as private data; this associates application-defined data with the object.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    new HResult SetPrivateData(ref Guid name, uint dataSize, IntPtr dataPtr);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Set an interface in the object's private data.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    new HResult SetPrivateDataInterface(ref Guid name,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object unknownInterfaceObject);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get a pointer to the object's data.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    new HResult GetPrivateData(ref Guid name, out int dataSize, out IntPtr dataPtr);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the parent of the object.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    new HResult GetParent(ref Guid rIId, out object pParent);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Enumerates the adapters (video cards).
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult EnumAdapters(uint numAdapter, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object adapter);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows DXGI to monitor an application's message queue for the alt-enter key sequence (which causes the application
    ///     to switch from windowed to fullscreen or vice versa).
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult MakeWindowAssociation(IntPtr windowHandle, uint flags);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get the window through which the user controls the transition to and from fullscreen.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult GetWindowAssociation(out IntPtr outHandleWindow);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates a swap chain.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult CreateSwapChain(object iUnknown, ref DxgiSwapChainDesc swapChainDesc,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object dxgiSwapChainObject);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Create an adapter interface that represents a software adapter.
    /// </summary>
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult CreateSoftwareAdapter(IntPtr moduleHandle, out IntPtr outPtr);
}
```

Все проблемы себя исчерпали, и код стал работать так как должен.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно, так как [InterfaceTypeAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.interfacetypeattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) определен как не наследуемый:

> [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Interface, **Inherited=false**)]
>   [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
>   public sealed class InterfaceTypeAttribute : Attribute

Comment: Хм, пометил все объекты, приложение стало падать...

Comment: @LLENN покажите полное определение производного интерфейса

Comment: Добавил полностью один из производных интерфейсов.

Comment: А результатом выполнения будет: `8015948170355802112`

Comment: @LLENN Методы базового интерфейса должны быть продублированы в интерфейсе-наследнике. Наследование в COM Interop не работает так, ожидалось. Методы базового класса автоматически в VTable не добавляются. Атрибуты к этому имеют косвенное отношение.